# Diff-in-diff with repeated cross-sectional data in R

Tags: r, causality

I’m using difference-in-differences design to estimate the impact of policy reform on depression prevalence using administrative data. My unit of analysis is a student who is age 18, enrolled to different types of higher education (Type A and B). The reform took effect at the same time (2015) for all of the students who are enrolled Type A education after 2015 but not students in Type B education. Those students who were enrolled Type A education before 2015 are not affected by the reform. That's why I cannot compare all cohorts enrolled in Type A and B education throughout the years although the pre&post data are available. But I can compare outcomes for one specific cohort (i.e., depression diagnosis for the first year Type A and B students who enrolled in 2014 vs. 2015).

The problem in this approach is that I use repeated cross sections. So, I think I should use the average of the outcome variable by cohort and type of education. Or can I use `feols` package with individual level data like below?

`mod1 <- feols(depression_dummy ~ type*year | ID year, data = X)`

Here depression_dummy refers to whether individual is depressed or not in a given year (0 or 1). Type refers to type of education (A or B), year refers to timeline from 2011 to 2017.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are not concerned about the coding, you may ask at https://stats.stackexchange.com/